# Trying to use periodic commit, Neo4j 2.1.2 refuses to run cypher queries

Tags: neo4j

I am working with large node and relationship files of several gigabytes each, so not using periodic commit isn't really an option. I've tested LOAD CSV and it works fine with smaller files on Neo4j 2.1.2, however, when I try to run something like this:

USING PERIODIC COMMIT

LOAD CSV FROM 'file://localhost/C:/dev/project.csv' AS line

CREATE (:Provider { Code: toInt(line[0]) })

The shell refuses to execute, instead displaying a red-background message "Type :help for a list of available commands." This confuses me because normally when I do something wrong, the shell doesn't hesitate to throw a syntax error message below.

OS: Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

Please use CTRL+R or CTRL+F5 to clear your browser cache. The client-side validation of the Neo4j browser-based shell is cached from a previous version of Neo4j.